# Clustering categorial data

Tags: clustering, categorical-data

I have a dataset with 100 nominal categorical variables with two levels each, for example:

Do you smoke? Yes/No

Do you like to dance? Yes/No

etc.

How can I cluster this dataset to group/create "profiles"?

I know a few type of clustering algorithms, like PCA, K-neighbors etc. But I think that I can't use these types of algorithms with non-quantitative variables. Is that true?

Thanks you.

Comment: Did you search the site? There are so many posts about clustering categotical data.

Comment: Here's a search to get you started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcategorical-data%5d%20%5bclustering%5d%20answers%3a1

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I recommend using [latent class clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model). This kind of clustering algorithm is appropriate for categorical responses. 
Your assessment that methods such as k-means clustering are probably not a good choice is correct.

Latent class clustering is a model-driven clustering algorithm. It assumes that we observe a mixture of a finite number of "types". Each type is defined by a probability distribution over the vector of responses. In your case, a type would be defined as a vector of 100 probabilities, where the jth probability gives the probability of selecting "yes" on the jth question.

Latent class clustering is [implemented as an R package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i10).

Answer (score -1):

You can do two data pre-processing transformations: mapping non-numeric data into binary dummies is a method. Check [this article's](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f0ab/93867dd49fb95124c422547634f5515252fa.pdf)data section. Your data is basically similar. After data pre-processing , SVM or another data classifier methods can be applied.

Comment: Why would SVM or a classifier method be used for a clustering analysis?